# Printing the number of lines

Tags: linux, bash

I have a directory that contains only .txt files. I want to print the number of lines for every file. When I write `cat file.txt | wc -l` the number of lines appears but when I want to make a script it's more complicated. I have this code:

```
for fis in `ls -R  $1`
do
        echo `cat $fis | wc -l`       

done
```

I tried: wc -l $fis , with awk,grep and it doesn't work. It tells that:

> cat: fis1: No such file or directory 
>   0

How can I do to print the number of lines?

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: You could just use `echo $( wc -l $fis )`  (alternate to backtick notation) but it sounds like you left the cat and it complained

Answer (score 1):

To find files recursively in subdirectories, use the `find` command, not `ls -R`, which is mainly intended for human reading.

```
find "$1" -type f -exec wc -l {} +
```

The problems with looping over the output of `ls -R` are:

1. Filenames with whitespace won't be parsed correctly.
2. It prints other output beside just the filenames.

Answer (score 0):

Not the problem here, but the echo command is more than needed:
You can use

```
wc -l "${fis}"
```

What goes wrong?
You have a subdir called `fis1`. Look to the output of `ls`:

```
# ls -R fis1
fis1:
file1_in_fis1.txt
```

When you are parsing this output, your script will try

```
echo `cat fis1: | wc -l`
```

The `cat` will tell you `No such file or directory` and `wc` counts `0`.

As @Barmar explained, `ls` prints additional output you do not want.

Do not try to patch your attempt by `| grep .txt` and `if [ -f "${fis}"]; then ..`, these will fail with `filename with spaces.txt`. So use `find` or `shopt` (and accept the answer of @Barmar or @Cyrus).